# Java test coverage tool to report coverage for just the changed files?

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage, test-reporting

What would be a good tool (similar to jest for javascript) to report unit test coverage for just the changes files in **Java projects**? We are planning to build this tool into each pull request on GitHub at workplace! 
Currently we are generating jacoco test reports on a daily-basis, but would be needing something that can be run on each build to target just the changes made. Appreciate the thoughts!